# Whether it will cause a reflow when changing the image's src attribution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As we know, a repaint occurs when changing elements skin, and a reflow acours when changing the layout. However, I have a problem whether it will cause a reflow when changing the img src attribution.

For exmaple, there are two images with different size, called A.png and B.png。

html:

```html
<button>change image src<button>
<img src="A.png">
```

Then we change the img src by js:

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('img').src = 'B.png';
}
```

Because A.png and B.png are in different size, so it will cause repaint and reflow when changing the img src.

But if we fix the img's size by css, as follow:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

If we change the img src again, whether it will cause both repaint and reflow ?

Comment: You can use Chrome's DevTools to [render paint rectangles around areas that need repainting](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas#use_chrome_devtools_to_quickly_identify_paint_bottlenecks). That's immensely helpful if you want to find out if something caused a reflow since you'll get paint rectangles outside of the element you changed.

Answer (score 1):

It might cause repaint but wont cause reflow, 
[Check this Visualization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dndeRnzkJDU)

It happens in the fraction of seconds that we don’t even notice that all this happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using css, changing the src attribute with javascript will just repaint with no reflow, because the dimensions of html image element are fixed even though the dimensions of actual image are different.

Before the click event on button occurs the css is already active so no reflow of image.

Following example will not cause a reflow,

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
document.querySelector('img').src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500';
}
```

```css
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button>change image src<button>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
```

This will cause a reflow,

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
document.querySelector('img').src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500';
}
```

```html
<button>change image src<button>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
```